# Playing BluRay discs

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation, vlc, blu-ray

*Things i Have tried.*

[Playing Blu-Ray and HD DVD Video](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/BluRayAndHDDVD)

MakeMKV and DumpHD do not work.

[Playing Blu-ray using VLC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140080/playing-blu-ray-using-vlc)

[Can linux play blu-rays](https://askubuntu.com/questions/565516/can-linux-play-blu-rays)

VLC error.

```
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'bluray:///dev/sr0'. Check the log for details.
```

MakeMKV Beta Log (last 9 lines)

```
Error 'Scsi error - ILLEGAL REQUEST:INVALID COMMAND OPERATION CODE' occurred while issuing SCSI command A40..0020..0BF to device 'SG:dev_11:0'
Error 'Scsi error - ILLEGAL REQUEST:INVALID COMMAND OPERATION CODE' occurred while issuing SCSI command A30..0020..0FF to device 'SG:dev_11:0'
Error 'Scsi error - ILLEGAL REQUEST:INVALID COMMAND OPERATION CODE' occurred while issuing SCSI command A40..0020..0FF to device 'SG:dev_11:0'
Error 'Scsi error - ILLEGAL REQUEST:INVALID COMMAND OPERATION CODE' occurred while issuing SCSI command A40..002000800 to device 'SG:dev_11:0'
Error 'Scsi error - ILLEGAL REQUEST:INVALID FIELD IN CDB' occurred while issuing SCSI command AD010..080002400 to device 'SG:dev_11:0'
Can't read AACS VID from disc - most likely current AACS host certificate is revoked by your drive
Highest AACS version is v25 , MKB saved as /home/neil/.MakeMKV/MKB_v25_Battleship.tgz
The volume key is unknown for this disc - video can't be decrypted
Failed to open disc
```

DumpHD 0.61 Log.

```
Initializing source... 
Disc type found: Blu-Ray BDMV
Collecting input files...
Source initialized
Identifying disc... OK
DiscID : 5CECDB072DC072F543F734AA708ADCCD4AF7EDDB
Searching disc in key database...
Disc not found in key database
```

mplayer

```
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ mplayer /media/xubuntu/BATTLESHIP_G51/BDMV/STREAM/00023.m2ts
MPlayer 1.1-4.8 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing /media/xubuntu/BATTLESHIP_G51/BDMV/STREAM/00023.m2ts.
libavformat version 54.20.3 (external)


Exiting... (End of file)
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$
```

VLC error

```
No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "undf". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.
```

Comment: Is this just a VLC issue? Try running in mplayer, in a terminal, any errors here? `mplayer /path/to/your/disc`

Comment: @markkirby Output added.

Comment: Strange, mplayer should play `.m2ts`, your not a noob so I assume you have `ubuntu-restricted-extras` for codecs.

Comment: @markkirby AASC encryption is the problem `MakeMKV` or `DumpHD` are meant to decrypt  the Blu ray disk so you can play it. so far i have not found a AASC decryption software for linux that works and the windows ones will not work under wine.